# How to normalizing data from the server in easy way in ngrx

Tags: redux, ngrx

I'm using ngrx/redux pattern in my app.

In [Normalizing State Shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) article, is it written that I should create a "table" for each object and link between them by an id.

for example:

```
posts = [{ id, author, comments: ["commentId1", "commentId2"....] }] 
comments = [{ id: 'commentId1', comment: '..' } … ]
```

From my server side I get the object nested within,

```
posts: [ { id, author, comments: [ { id, comment } ] } ..]
```

So I need to write a code to refactor the object that match the Normalized State? for each arrays properties in my objects?

Is sound a big work to do. First, am I right I need to do that? Second, If so, there is a easy way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem. I ended up using [NGRX Entity](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity) with different states. In your case, one state for posts and one for comments. One could go further and normalize everything much more, but as you said it is a lot of work and I am not sure if it is worth it.

I found Todd Motto's tutorials to be really good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=al0LNgH3I4A

One way or another, you will still need a mapper that maps your server object into models you can use in your app. Different selectors can than help you to easily get the right comments for a given post.